# How to call SQL View Dapper c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

Is there any way to call a sql view by using Dapper c# ?

I already know how to call stored procedures with that, but when it comes to views I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: A view is like a table "Select * from View"

Comment: Now knowing that a view is like a table, are you able to use their documentation to find out what you need?

Comment: Same way you `SELECT` from a table.  If you want to map the View results to something than you need POCO's that represent your View

Comment: Thanks all . I got it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A view works like a table from the perspective of queries, including how filters and parameters work - so something like:

```
string region = ...
var data = connection.Query<SomeType>(
    "select * from SomeView where Region = @region", new { region }).AsList();
```

Comment: native EF core can do the same, but how to do that without entity pointing?

Comment: @anatol what do you mean by "without entity pointing"? what is "entity pointing"?

Comment: I mean `SomeType` as it is, etc